# Unable to Load PowerShell Modules at the beginning of each script session - function capacity 4096 has been exceeded for this scope?

Tags: powershell

I need to load up all of these modules at the beginning of my PowerShell script.

However, the code I am using below, throws the error that it cannot even find the despite I have put **Import-Module PowerShellGet** in Line #1

Script:

```
Import-Module PowerShellGet

$ModuleList = @('ExchangeOnlineManagement', 'Microsoft.Graph', 'Az.Accounts', 'Az.Resources', 'MSOnline', 'AzureAD')

ForEach($module in $ModuleList) {
    
    If (Get-InstalledModule -Name $module -AllVersions)
    {
        $paramUpdateModule = @{
            Name    = $module
            Force   = $true
            Verbose = $true
        }
        
        Update-Module @paramUpdateModule
    }
    Else
    {
        $paramInstallModule = @{
            Name               = $module
            Scope              = 'AllUsers'
            AllowClobber       = $true
            Verbose            = $true
            SkipPublisherCheck = $true
            Force              = $true
        }
        
        Install-Module @paramInstallModule
    }
}
```

Error Screenshot:
[image]

How to fix the above issue to ensure I can load up the modules at the beginning of the script?

Comment: You can try setting [`$MaximumFunctionCount`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/blob/main/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_Preference_Variables.md#maximumfunctioncount) to 32768

Comment: That or move to PowerShell Core if possible.